# @use shows undefined variable constantly

Tags: sass

I am migrating from `libsass` to `dartscss`, so moving from `@import` to `@use`. I have around 20 sites and the way I have my sites is to have one scss folder with all of my scss files and then have a site config per site that uses variables to override the default colours.

**My site structure**

```
scss/
├─ import.scss
├─ base/
│  ├─ _reset.scss
site1/
├─ scss/
│  ├─ settigns/
│  │  ├─ _config.scss
│  import.scss
```

In **site1/scss/settings/_config.scss** I have the following code:

```
$bgc: red;
```

And in my **site1/scss/import.scss** I have:

```
@use "settings/config" as *;
@use "../../scss/import.scss";
```

And finally in `../../scss/import.scss` I have a simple test call to see if it works.

```
body {
   background-color: $bgc;
}
```

When I view my site I get `undefined variable` and `$bgc` doesn't render. I would like to keep the structure I had before since I have many sites that share the same scss folder and all worked fine before when I used @import.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a step in your setup. The @ use directive tells the Sass compiler to pull in the imported code, but it doesn't actually set the variables in your current scope. In order to make sure the variables are available in your current scope, you need to use the @ import directive.

So, you would need to update your site1/scss/import.scss to look like this:

@ import "settings/config";
@ use "../../scss/import.scss";

(Make sure to remove space after @)

This will ensure that the variables set in the config file are available in your current scope.

Comment: oh. I thought the @import rule was going to be deprecated and everything had to be @use?!

Comment: The @ import directive is still supported in Sass, but the @ use directive provides a better way to structure your code and helps prevent unnecessary duplication. The @ use directive allows you to import code from other files without polluting the current scope, so it is generally preferred over @ import.

Comment: ok I see, so when they do remove @import support in the future, how would it work otherwise?

Comment: If @ import is removed in the future, then you would need to use @ use to import code from other files. The syntax would be similar to what you are currently using, but instead of @ import, you would use @ use. For example, in your site1/scss/import.scss file, you would need to use the following syntax: 

@ use "settings/config" as *;
@ use "../../scss/import.scss";

This would ensure that the variables set in the config file are available in your current scope.

Comment: Yeah I tried @ use "settings/config" as *; (see tree above) that didn't work as it said the variable isn't defined. I prefer not to use @import as I have a lot of sites and don't want to use redo a lot of changes.

Comment: You have a confusing directory structure. But, I would make an index file, and @forward all the partials in your structure. Your main scss file that gets would "use" the index file and that would get compiled. But it is more involved than that. Watch this video all the way through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0&list=PLlwbAGSVMKHrkw8qJHSXePgvYRwy9i-8Q&index=42